# Import Data to new excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import a set of data to my new excel document from a data dump from Microsoft Forms. I have the code working to where I can select the file and it imports all rows. I have tried to find how to do this online but can only find a way to do it by stating every column A to W with its own code.

```
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
i = 1

With Range("A1")
   If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "" Then
   Else
     Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i)
     x = x + 1
   End If
End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the last row and copy once:

```vb
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If Not IsEmpty(.Range("A1")) Then
        .Range("A1:W" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    End If
End With
```